# iPhone: First song does not stop before we start next song

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I play a song by buffering in my application.

I want to play another song (by clicking a button).

But it plays both songs together. It does not stop the first song even when I try to stop it.

I referred matt gallagher [tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html) and here is my code:

```
[streamer stop];


 - (void)stop
 {
        @synchronized(self)
        {
            if (state == AS_WAITING_FOR_DATA || state == AS_STARTING_FILE_THREAD)
                return;
            if (audioQueue &&
                (state == AS_PLAYING || state == AS_PAUSED ||
                    state == AS_BUFFERING || state == AS_WAITING_FOR_QUEUE_TO_START))
    {
        self.state = AS_STOPPING;
        stopReason = AS_STOPPING_USER_ACTION;
        err = AudioQueueStop(audioQueue, true);
        if (err)
        {
            [self failWithErrorCode:AS_AUDIO_QUEUE_STOP_FAILED];
            return;
        }
    }
    else if (state != AS_INITIALIZED)
    {
        self.state = AS_STOPPED;
        stopReason = AS_STOPPING_USER_ACTION;
    }
    seekWasRequested = NO;
}

while (state != AS_INITIALIZED)
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
}
}
```

This `streamer` calls the stop method of buffering.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in the debugger? Does the AudioQueueStop call get reached?

Comment: @onnoweb: Yes we go through debugger & AudioQueueStop also call.

Comment: Have you checked the result code? http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117-CH5g-RCM0127

Comment: You should show all of your code, upload the project to github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made you a function that can kill the old player when you start a new stream :

```
- (void)playURL:(NSURL*)url {
    if (streamer == nil) {
        streamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:url];
        return;
    }
    if ([streamer isPlaying]) {
        [streamer stop];
        [streamer release];
    }
    streamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:url];
}
```

Install it in your viewcontroller and use it instead of the raw **[[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithURL:url]**